# Angular JS + Asp.Net MVC basic example; Angular not been referred

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I know this is the basic question, i tried to find a workaround and it works. But i want to know what i'm missing here.

I have created a sample application with Asp.Net MVC and angular, just tried to display a hardcoded text to MVC view from angular and its not getting displayed. I guess this happens as it couldnt find angular.js reference. I tried to view source and could find the reference.

In the later case i provided full path of Angular.js file and its working fine.

Code:
BundleConfig.cs

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AMV_Angular1")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Controllers","*.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/AMV_Angular1.js",
            "~/Scripts/Angular.js"));
```

Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="helloAngular"></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="cnt">

    <input type="text" ng-model="helloAngular" />
    <h1>{{helloAngular}}</h1>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AMV_Angular1")
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript File

```
(function () {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller("cnt", function ($scope) {
        $scope.helloAngular = "this is from Angular";
    });

}());
```

The below is output in HTML and Source of rendered HTML

[image]
Below is my directory structure

[image]

Comment: are there any errors in the console? What happens when you run the example? Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : There are no errors in console. when the run the example there is {{hello Angular}} display (which i have displayed in the image). Please if you can click the image i have uploaded, it would provide all details i could have detailed. Please let me know if any other input is needed. Thanks

Comment: your minimal example should be in the form of code; not screenshots.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : Question edited. Code snippet provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are loading your scripts in the wrong order. Angular.js should be loaded before your controllers etc due their dependecy on angular.js.

Try to add it first in your bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AMV_Angular_source")
            .Include("~/Scripts/Angular.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AMV_Angular1")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Controllers","*.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/AMV_Angular1.js"));
```

Comment: Wonderful. Works like charm. Thought its due to angular not been refereed. its stupid that i couldn't recognize it. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @Ramu Great! Small details are sometimes the hardest to catch, an honest mistake. Have a nice day!